# UITextField return key on subview

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've got a `UIViewController` with an additional small `UIView` I created on top of it (subview). When I click a button this view hovers to the center of the screen. The issue is the i've got a `UITextField` in the additional `UIView` and i cannot seem to get the return key to work.

Although I set my `IBAction` to the event "Editing did end" of the text field, when i click the return key, the `IBAction` doesn't run.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show some code? Have you **delegated** the textfield to the file's owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just set Your Delegate for example :- `yourtextfile.delegate=self;` and also dont forget to add delegate method in to .h file

`@interface contacts_detailView : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>`

and then you  delegate `textFieldDidEndEditing`

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
//your new view apear code here 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure UITextFieldDelegate at interface

Comment: I already have <UITextFieldDelegate> at interface. Although i'm not sure it's a must. Anyhow, it didn't solve the issue

Comment: add delegate to your textfield 
textfiled.delegate =self

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on "Return" doesn't trigger an "Editing did end" event. Only when you'll call resignFirstResponder on the UITextField will you see the event triggered.

What you should do is set your UIViewController as the delegate of the UITextField and implement the method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Finally! Thanks a lot! I don't know why the others didn't work but this one sure did. I'm pretty sure i saw once that attaching an IBAction to the "End Editing" event did the trick but i'll check on that one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, delegate the TextField to the file's owner like this:

`yourtextField.delegate = self` in your viewDidLoad.

And then add this to the view controller

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write more code for key board return. Please write this in your .m file , it will work for any number of text field , no need to write again again for different textfield.

use `<UItextfieldDelegate>`  in your .h file. Then make wiring with fileowner in nib file.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
     return YES;
     }
```